# Broken link when I try to create a symbolic link

Tags: linux, symlink

I have to create a symbolic link but when I try it, I have a broken link.

I'm using this command : `ln -s /usr/share/java/tomcat-juli.jar /opt/persyst/apache7/bin`

I don't understand why the link is broken. What should I do to resolve it please ?

Comment: I presume that `/usr/share/java/tomcat-juli.jar` actually exists?

Comment: @EricRenouf Yes, it does exist. And I have an other link with the same source somewhere else, and it works

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you do not have the permission to traverse the full path. Try to split the command in two to see where it fails:

```
cd /opt/persyst/apache7/
ln -s /usr/share/java/tomcat-juli.jar bin
```